# How is a function of a function defined?

Tags: functions

Commonly functions have a value as their input. For instance the square function from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{\geq0}$ can be written:

$\begin{align*}
f:&\; \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^{\geq0}\\
&\;x \mapsto x^2
\end{align*}$

But what about functions like $\int$ or $^{-1}$? Could these also be described in a similar way?

Comment: Well why not: the evaluation integral (for example) is a function from the (Riemann) integrable functions to the reals, so $\int:\{$Riemann integrable functions$\}\to\mathbb{R}$, given by $f\to\int_a^bf$. In general you can write down any map as $f:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is your domain and $\mathcal{D}$ your range, and this could be (in principle) any sets. By the way, the more commonly used notation is $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, not with the superscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it's a bit more complicated. The $\int^b_a$ is a [linear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form) so you have $\int:L^1[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$. You can read about $L^1$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Regarding $^{-1}$ it can mean different things but if you mean inverse function then let us denote $I\subset\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ to be the set of functions which have an inverse function. Now you will have $^{-1}:I\rightarrow I$. If you want to understand it well you should read about functional anlysis.